# How to structure a microservice management layer calls

Tags: client, microservices, rpc, api-design

I am building a microservice that will have a management layer, and another corresponding microservice for a public api. The management layer's client will be imported into the api service as well as a few other apps. What I am wondering is what the proper way to structure the mgmt layer's calls would be. I'm using rpc.

For example, let's say the service contains Human, Dog, Food. Food has to be owned by a Human OR Dog, not both and not neither.

Now since the mgmt service will only be accessed by client and not url, would it be better to define the specs like:

```
POST: /humans/id/food     Client call: mgmtService.createFoodForHuman(humanId, Food)
POST: /dogs/id/food       Client call: mgmtService.createFoodForDog(dogId, Food)
```

or

```
POST: /food               Client call: mgmtService.createFood(Food)
```

where the second instance of Food will require the user to pass in one of human id or dog id.

To me, the first example seems more straightforward from a code-client perspective since the methods are more defined and the second example doesn't give any info of what kind of id is needed, but I am interested if there is any thoughts on which one is best practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is actually depends, on larger scale you would want to apply the first method. Sometimes, when you works with the other teams to build a complex services, it is possible that the other teams has to fix your bug because of your absent or any case where you can't fix the bug that time, if the bug is really an urgent cases, you wouldn't want it becomes a blocker because they did not understand how your code works.

Well, you can always provide a documentation for every API details on your platform such as Confluence, but still that would takes time to look for it.

On the other hand, with second method you can achieve that one for all API.

TL;DR -> Large scale 1st method, small scale 2nd method.